# DataSet panel (Report Data) in SSRS designer is gone

Tags: sql, visual-studio, user-interface, reporting-services, toolbox

In the layout screen of an SSRS designer e.g. Visual Studio, I have lost the report data panel.

It has disappeared and I can't remember what it is called in order to get it back.

This usually lists the following items:

- Built-in Fields
- Parameters
- Images
- Data Sources
- Datasets

Previously it was in the same area as the general Toolbox and Server explorer panels.

Does anyone know how to restore it?

Comment: I have seen cases where an error dialog has displayed upon first report load, and this seemingly prevented the Report Data window from appearing. Even after displaying the window using suggestions on this page, it was still blank. Reopening the report (without closing it) finally fixed the problem.

Comment: @ErikE i have exactly the same problem. It also occurs with the properties window. The error I get is 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: name'

Answer (score 384):

With a report (rdl) file selected in your solution, select **View** and then **Report Data**.

It is a shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: +1 Spent over 30mins looking for this. Funny how something so essential is so hidden. One would think it would be placed under View or Report menus without having to select the report.

If the UI has to be dumbed down let it be dumbed down all the way

Comment: I assume everyone (like myself) stopped looking once they got past the 'Other Windows' sub-menu?

Comment: i still don't see it in VS 2012 but the keyboard shortcut worked.

Comment: of course, right after i post my comment i looked at the bottom of the view menu and there it was.  =p

Comment: I found that rdl file has to be selected and active in main workspace area for Report Data to be available in View dropdown. If report is selected in solution explorer only Report Data will remain hidden.

Comment: I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36819822/1042705) is how it should become visible

Comment: some people don't have Report Data in View for some reason.   ctrl alt d did the trick though, thank you.  this was vs 2015 ent ssdt 14.1.xxx

Comment: @Microsoft - when you have a stackoverflow question to find something in your menu that has over 128k views with 167+ and the answer 340+ - then you have to think - is it the user or an issue with the software and usability? 

(Spoiler - It's the software!)

Comment: After VS crashed (and auto-restarted) the Report Data dissapeared on me, and was looking like a madman where it is, and eventually seen this, but still wasn't there! After restarting Visual Studio manually, and re-opening the project, it reappeared.

Answer (score 55):

If you are using BIDS with SQL 2008 R2 you can only get the "Report Data" menu by clicking inside the actual report layout itself.

1. Click inside the actual report layout.
2. Now select "View" from the main menu bar.
3. Now select "Report Data" which is the last item.

Comment: This works with VS2012 if you have the SQL Server Tools installed

Comment: Oh godddd. step 1 is so important

Answer (score 37):

With a .rdl, .rdlc or similar file selected, you can either:

- Click View -> Report Data or...
- Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>***CTRL***</kbd> + <kbd>***ALT***</kbd> + <kbd>***D***</kbd>

[image: Example]

Comment: Just a tip - if the report is in Preview mode, the Report Data option will be greyed out (VS 2013 at least)

Comment: This is strange - you come 6 years later and copy my answer?

Answer (score 23):

For future people CTRL+ALT+D or just view > report data in ancient ssrs 2008 VS BI. In newer 2017 SSRS, it's still the same. Funny how they change a bunch of things around, yet kept this the same.

Comment: Interesting caveat: I have one monitor scaled to 125% for recording a presentation.  When I opened VS 2017 / SSRS 2017 on that monitor there was no Report Data option in the View menu.  I guess somehow Windows rendered the View menu so that the Report Data option fell off the bottom.  It still looked the same when I dragged it across to the monitor that was scaled to 100%.  It was only when I closed Visual Studio and reopened it afresh on the 100% scaled monitor that I could see the Report Data option in the menu.

Comment: Same for VS2019

Comment: I'm in VS 2022 and I don't know WHAT happened.  It was there yesterday.  I had the report rdl file selected in the object explorer.  Design view was displayed.  Report Data was nowhere to be found on the View menu.  CTRL+ALT+D saved the day.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

View -> Datasets (bottom of menu, above Refresh)

Answer (score 7):

First you have to click on the report, Then
View -> Report Data

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with SQL 2008 R2 then from `View`---->`Report` Data option at bottom

Answer (score 0):

First Click any where on the Report layout in Visual Studio and then go to View/Report Data at the bottom of View Menu

Comment: Other than omitting a precondition, this seems to repeat answers from about 2011.