# How can I add a static Image Logo to a generated PDF using the SQL Server Reporting Tools Designer?

Tags: reporting-services, pdf-generation

Using the Report designer in Visual Studio, I dragged and dropped a an Image control over onto the header but I'm lost as to what to do next. I need to choose the **Source** which gives me a choice between `External`, `Embedded`, `Database` and custom expression. I also have a **Value** property but it didn't prompt me to choose a file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this:

If I open the report and give the focus to the report form (not one of the controls), I get a new menu item called `Report` at the top of Visual Studio. Open the `Embedded Images...` dialog and I can add a new image there. Then close that dialog and give focus to the image control that I want to have the static image. I can set its value property to one of the embedded images that I have added using the Embedded Images dialog.

Answer (score 1):

On your Report Data view box (Where the report parameters, datasets etc) are shown, there is also a folder for Images.

Right click that and add the image you want.

Now when you use your image control you can choose Embedded and drop down any of the imagess included in the Images folder.

The External source is good for adding in a URL to the image and database is when the image is stored in one of your datasets.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678322/dataset-panel-in-ssrs-designer-is-gone) is the solution if the report data view screen is missing

Comment: I know the view box you are talking about but its now showing up when it usually does. Thats the one with my datasets and then a TON of attributes or something? Any Idea where I would be able to go to reopen that window?