# I lost datasets pane in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I'm developing a report in the Business Intelligence studio and I lost my dataset. The pane was near toolbox, and it is gone. What is the name of the pane I should to reopen?

Comment: try `Window->Reset Window Layout` to reset the layout

Comment: @JosephH, Just tried. Does not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataSet panel in SSRS designer is gone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678322/dataset-panel-in-ssrs-designer-is-gone)

Answer (score 236, accepted):

If anyone is interested:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> combo helped me.

Comment: It's also usually found in the menu: `View > Report Data`

Comment: what causes it to disappear - happened to me too - the project is a report type project so you would think that would stay visible.

Comment: Worked for me too. Just a note about the View > Report Data menu. It looks to only be visible if the focus in on the actual report. Have the focus on the toolbox for example and the menu item is not even listed, let alone greyed out.

Comment: And it is so very !intuitively the very bottom option.  That is THE most important thing after the designer itself.  Should be at the top.  Thanks StackOverflow.  Saved me yet again.

Answer (score 40):

In Visual Studio 2013 running [SSDTBI for VS 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313) the option has moved to the "View" menu, and confusingly it only shows **if an actual report has focus**. So click somewhere in your report, and *then* click "View"

[image]

Or as stated by others <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> still works, though only *if you have a report focussed*.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason Ctrl + Alt + D didn't work for me.

I found it under Data -> Show Data Sources...

You would think it would be under View.

Answer (score 3):

I am using VS 2010 and Ctrl + Alt + D worked for me. 
You have to click somewhere on the report to work this.

Similarly:

Ctrl + Alt + L for Solution Explorer

Ctrl + Alt + S for Server explorer

F4 for Properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there's no Data in your top menu, there's no option DataSource Window to click. Luckily often Ctrl + Alt + D works.